# Ubuntu 16.04 does not detect monitor

Tags: boot, monitor

Ubuntu 16.04 does not detect the desktop monitor ViewSonic VG1921wm. Until the Grub the monitor is on, after booting the message 'no signal' appears. If I boot through the recovery mode the monitor is detected, but every time I need to boot through the recovery mode. This does not resolve the regular boot.
How to resolve this. Thanks a lot
Addition: If I boot with Linux 3.13.0-92-generic (left-over of 14.04, but boots into 16.04) the monitor is recognized. With 4.4.0-34-generic it is not.
As of October 8, 2016 this problem remains. Anyone with a possible solution?